# Python + Kivy - IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, kivy

````
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore
from kivy.utils import platform

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        # загрузка сохраненного текста из файла
        store = JsonStore('data.json')
        if store.exists('text'):
            self.text = store.get('text')['value']
        else:
            self.text = ''

        # создание текстового окна для ввода
        self.input_box = TextInput(text=self.text, multiline=True)
        save_button = Button(text="Сохранить")
        save_button.bind(on_press=self.save_text)  # привязка функции к событию нажатия кнопки

        # создание блока прокрутки для текстового блока
        scroll_view = ScrollView()

        # создание текстового блока для отображения отформатированного текста
        formatted_text = self.format_text(self.text)
        text_label = Label(text=formatted_text)

        # добавление текстового блока в блок прокрутки
        scroll_view.add_widget(text_label)

        # создание главного макета и добавление в него виджетов
        root = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        root.add_widget(self.input_box)
        root.add_widget(save_button)
        root.add_widget(scroll_view)

        return root

    def save_text(self, instance):
        # получение текста из текстового окна
        text = self.input_box.text

        # сохранение текста в файл
        store = JsonStore('data.json')
        store.put('text', value=text)

        # обновление отформатированного текста в текстовом блоке
        formatted_text = self.format_text(text)
        scroll_view = self.root.children[-1].children[-1]
        text_label = scroll_view.children[0]
        text_label.text = formatted_text

    def format_text(self, text):
        # замена мест переменных в тексте на их значения
        formatted_text = text.replace("gpu", gpu)
        formatted_text = formatted_text.replace("cpu", cpu)

        return formatted_text


def create_json_file():
    store = JsonStore('data.json')
    if not store.exists('text'):
        store.put('text', value='')


def check_json_file():
    store = JsonStore('data.json')
    return True if store.exists('text') else False


# тестовые значения
gpu = "Nvidia GeForce GTX 1080"
cpu = "Intel Core i7-9700K"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if platform == 'android':
        from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission

        request_permissions([Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])
    if not check_json_file():
        create_json_file()
    MyApp().run()```
````

Возникает следующая ошибка, при нажатии на кнопку сохранения информации в поле ввода. Как можно исправить?

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):    File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 86, in <module>
 MyApp().run()    File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 956, in run
 runTouchApp()    File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 574, in runTouchApp
 EventLoop.mainloop()    File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 339, in mainloop
 self.idle()    File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 383, in idle
 self.dispatch_input()    File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 334, in dispatch_input
 post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))    File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 263, in post_dispatch_input
 listener.dispatch('on_motion', etype, me)    File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch   File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1691, in on_motion
 self.dispatch('on_touch_down', me)    File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch    File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1708, in on_touch_down
 if w.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch    File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 589, in on_touch_down
 if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch   File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 151, in on_touch_down
 self.dispatch('on_press')    File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 727, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch    File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1307, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch    File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1231, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 52, in save_text
 scroll_view = self.root.children[-1].children[-1]
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^  IndexError: list index out of range*
```

Comment: `IndexError: list index out of range` - ошибка означает, что вы при запросе элемента вышли за пределы массива. Похоже, ваш массив пуст